# does AngularJS directive prefixes affect the speed of HTML compilation?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

As you know it's possible to use angularJS directives as attributes with different prefixes:
`data-` , `x-`, `_`, `:`. and also it's possible to use a directive as attribute or a distinct element and comment.
do the prefixes or the type affect the speed of HTML compilation? if so, which is the fastest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js) for `compile.js` there is a regex:

```
var PREFIX_REGEXP = /^((?:x|data)[\:\-_])/i;
```

The name is always *normalized* with this function:

```
function directiveNormalize(name) {
  return camelCase(name.replace(PREFIX_REGEXP, ''));
}
```

And the `directiveNormalize` function is used for all compile operations that use the name of the attribute.

So, it should **not** make any difference from a compile performance perspective.

Comment: thanks. this is about the name of directive. how about the type restriction?(element/attribute/comment)

Comment: I would expect no difference in these as well.  Are you seeing something that makes you think there is a difference?

Comment: Actually I have a view in which I have to implement some logic with directives. the page loads a little slow. trying to figure out the reason, I thought may be the directives affect the speed of compilation.